# Unresolved promise angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ngResource` to get the data from the server side into my view, and I have a custom action that I defined that gets items count, it looks like this in the code (controller):

```
$scope.totalItems = Item.item_count().total
```

And in my view :

```
This customer bought {{totalItems}}
```

In my view I just get the `This customer bought` without other part being interpolated. However also when I do this :

```
console.log(Item.item_count().total)
console.log(Item.item_count())
```

I get the `undefined` for first statement but for second one I get this :

[image]

Why am I unable to access the total count from the view, and what do I do to fix this?

**Update (service code) :**

```
app.factory('Item', function($resource) {
  return $resource(
        window.config.API_URL + '/:apiPath/:id', {
            id: '@id',
            apiPath: '@apiPath'
        }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                  apiPath: 'items'
                },
                isArray: true
            },
            item_count: {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                  apiPath: 'item_count'
                },
                isArray: false
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Please add your Item Factory/Service code, without it, we can't really help you.

Comment: @yvesmancera I updated it with service code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `$promise` and pass in a callback like so:

```
Item.item_count().$promise.then(function(data) {
  $scope.totalItems = data.total;
});
```

If you need to have the data resolved before loading your view, you can use $stateProvider to resolve it.  This should give you a good idea how and some implications of using it: http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/02/angularjs-pitfalls-using-ui-routers-resolve/.

Answer (score 0):

look like you get a promise returned.
Try calling `console.log(Item.item_count().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your other code my guess is the line 
`$scope.totalItems = Item.item_count().total` is getting resolved before the promise is getting resolved.  That line should be in sort of then catch for the promise.  However this is just a guess since you haven't actually posted this code.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Item.item_count()` returns a promise you have to wait until it is resolved before you set `$scope.totalItems`:

```
Item.item_count().then(function(item_count) {
  $scope.totalItems = item_count.total;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `scope.` from your `{{}}` in the view.

```
This customer bought {{totalItems}}
```